# Please tell me what the problem is c# regex.split()

Tags: c#, regex

```
string temp_constraint = row["Constraint_Name"].ToString();
string split_string = "FK_"+tableName+"_";
string[] words = Regex.Split(temp_constraint, split_string);
```

I am trying to split a string using another string.

```
temp_constraint = FK_ss_foo_ss_fee
split_string = FK_ss_foo_
```

but it returns a single dimension array with the same string as in temp_constraint

Please help

Comment: what are you trying to get?  And I agree with Darin.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that you Darin, I almost answered teh question by accident

Comment: @Henk, now when I open the profile there are many accepted answers. Strange. I guess some caching issues, or the OP really worked on it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your split operation works fine for me:

```
string temp_constraint = "FK_ss_foo_ss_fee";
string split_string = "FK_ss_foo_";
string[] words = Regex.Split(temp_constraint, split_string);
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(">{0}<", word);
}
```

Output:

```
><
>ss_fee<
```

I think the problem is that your variables are not set to what you think they are. You will need to debug to find the error elsewhere in your program.

I would also avoid using Split for this (both `Regex` and `String.Split`). You aren't really splitting the input - you are removing a string from the start. Split might not always do what you want. Imagine if you have a foreign key like the following:

```
FK_ss_foo_ss_fee_FK_ss_foo_ss_bee
```

You want to get `ss_fee_FK_ss_foo_ss_bee` but split would give you `ss_fee_` and `ss_bee`. This is a contrived example, but it does demonstrate that what you are doing is not a split.

Comment: the problem is occurring at the 
split_string = "FK_"+tableName+"_";

I used a break point to check the value of tableName and it is exactly showing what I wanted. I am not understanding the reason. When I use a static string, the splitting is occuring properly. But its not the same when I am using the variable

Comment: @Yash: Your variable probably contains some symbol that is not what you think it is. Perhaps an extra space. The problem is most likely with the contents of 'tableName'.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) instead

```
string[] words = 
    temp_constraint.Split(new []{split_string}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Even the method you suggested doesnt work. I tried that too. I am not sure why it doesnt work when I am using a variable to construct split_string variable as such. Instead I used string.replace(splitstring, ""); and it worked properly and it serves my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

string split uses a character array to split text and does the split by each character which is not often ideal.

The following article shows how to split text by an entire word

http://www.bytechaser.com/en/functions/ufgr7wkpwf/split-text-by-words-and-not-character-arrays.aspx